# AngularJS Form Validation Parent form valid when child input element invalid

Tags: forms, angularjs

I am attempting to validate a form using AngularJS's built in $invalid property. The form has some html inputs which have the required="required" attribute and a submit button which inspects formName.$invalid prior to allowing the user to make a server side request. The browser I am currently testing is IE11. When I submit the form entering only the first input element to appear in the form with valid data, and without entering any data into the forms remaining child elements, the child elements without valid data appear in the debugger window as invalid = true, however, the form itself appears as invalid = false. It appears that angularJS shows the form's validation state per the first item to appear in the form. A work around would be to explicity validate each form child element but I would rather not explicitly inspect each input's $invalid property when submitting the form.

Seeking any suggestions to resolve the issue, and thanks in advance

Update issue resolved by removing the following code from the angular controller.

```
if (!Array.indexOf) {
Array.prototype.indexOf = function (obj, start) {
    for (var i = (start || 0); i < this.length; i++) {
        if (this[i] == obj) {
            return i;
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: angularjs check all child element and not just one. if you can share the html, that would be great

Comment: Is that all HTML you can do ? You should post at least double that much to get a decent solution. And don't let anyone trick you with that **[SSCCE](http://sscce.org)** mambo jambo !

Comment: I didn't want to post too much html, and sorry if it is hard to read. I also created a jsfiddle and was able to validate the parent form based upon its child elements. I'm not sure why it is not working in the full solution. http://jsfiddle.net/tgibson1/U3pVM/7776/

Comment: Issue resolved by removing this line of code from the AngularJS controller.